# Is there an Algorithm in ElasticSearch which gives similarity between vectors?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, machine-learning, deep-learning, elastic-stack

Before I start, I seriously have no idea what Elastic is and How it works. I am ML Engineer and have recently been assigned the task for `Image - Image similarity`. I developed a model which will give me a vector for every image and then I'll have to compare the distances between the vectors provided by the model such as `Manhattan, Euclidean, cosine etc`. I could do it easily but the problem is that I have this huge data around 20M images and I can not store all the vectors in memory for starters and even if I do, it is practically impossible for me to compare with each and every unit as it'll be `O(12M)` comparisons.

So I want to know that are there any algorithms for Vectors searching just there is text search algo like `Okapi BM25`.

My vectors look like:
`[0.2,0.1,0.04,......]` etc. They can be any dimensional depending on the use case. But is there any algorithm which can get me `top-k` search results.

Our team is using `MongoDB` if that needed information.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch can do Cosine Similarity "out of the box" (as in - no plugins necessary) since version 7.7 i think. there are also plugins that implement other algorithms but i don't have any experience with them. bare in mind, that elasticsearch is very CPU and disk I/O heavy so cosine similarity can be slow for very large datasets.
since you are not familiar with ES at all, i wont go into details here, you'll have to learn how to use it first.

if your data is already in MongoDB, you'll need to index the JSON documents in Elasticsearch using the "dense_vector" data type, and then you could use the cosine_similarity built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Elasticsearch for searching similar images, too.
This is my example query to do that.( It calculates the similarity score )

```
script_query = {
        "script_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {"match": {"property1": a}},
                        {"match": {"property2": b}}]}},
            "script": {
                "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'fvec') + 1.0",
                "params": {"query_vector": fvec}
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How much time is it taking? I think ElasticSearch take `O(n)` time. 1 Vs the Rest comparisons. How much time is your algo taking?